# Angular Condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me! I need to create condition IF...ELSE with AngularJS
my index.html is:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item-container" ng-repeat="item in categories track by $index"> <a href="#/parts/{{ item.idold }}">
<ons-row>
<ons-col>
<div class="name">
{{ item.category }}  - {{ item.orgs }}
</div>
</ons-col>
<ons-col width="40px"></ons-col>
</ons-row></a>
</ons-list-item>
```

Where **{{ item.orgs }}** can be 0 or 1...I need to make IF {{ item.orgs }}=1 -> href="#/parts/{{ item.idold }}" ELSE href="#/parts/detail/{{ item.id }}"

Comment: You should use `ng-href` in your `<a>` tag if your links are going to have markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?:` conditional operators in AngularJS expressions. They work the same as other languages.

```
<a ng-href="#/parts/{{ item.orgs == 1 ? item.idold : item.id }}">
```

You're injecting backward compatibility rules into your templates. That's not a good practice. As @WillsonMock said, it's better to do this somewhere else like a controller or directive.

Alternatively, if the default value for `item.idold` is falsy then you won't need the `?:` operators. Just use a `||` OR logical operator. JavaScript will use the value of the last truthy variable.

So this can be simplified.

```
<a ng-href="#/parts/{{ item.idold || item.id }}">
```

I find the above easier to read for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try creating a function in your scope that does the logic you're describing and then invoke the function within the `{{ items.orgs }}` part? That should work and output correctly to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-if

```
<a ng-href="#/parts/{{ item.idold }}" ng-if="item.orgs">{{ item.category }} </a>
<a ng-href="#/parts/{{ item.id }}" ng-if="!item.orgs">{{ item.category }} </a>
```